# Unity: Keyboard Shortcut for "Open Terminal" doesn't work anymore

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

Ctrl-Alt-T doesn't open a terminal. How can I fix this? Where can I verify/change the shortcuts?

I had a lot of problems with the focus behaviour of my unity desktop. This problems have gone now - I don't know why after a few reboots it was back to almost normal... - but the problem that I can't open a terminal window with the keyboard shortcut still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Search in Unity for 'Keyboard Shortcuts'. All the goodies are in there, including the shortcut for opening a terminal.